# App engine 1.4.0 urlfetch() data over 1M

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch

the version of my app engine is 1.4.0.the data dem.bil is under the /war/dem.bil directory.and these are my codes to fetch the data dem.bil that is 3M:
                        try{
                        URLConnection a = url.openConnection();
            InputStream b = a.getInputStream();
            int len = a.getContentLength();
            if (len < 0) {
                return null;
            }
            //System.out.println("Total: "+len);
            byte[] c = new byte[len];
            b.read(c,0,len);
            return c;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
                }
            }

i know the  version 1.4.0 increased the URLFetch response limit to 32MB,but when it goes to InputStream b = a.getInputStream(); it's debug is                                              "com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.ResponseTooLargeException: The response from url localhost:8888/dem.bil was too large. ".so can someone can tell me why?or some wrong with my codes?

Comment: Please don't post duplicates; just edit your question instead. [a problem about urlfetch over 1M in app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421756/a-problem-about-urlfetch-over-1m-in-app-engine)

Answer (score 1):

Since the 1.4.0 version was released, the limit was raised to 32mb.

See: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/12/happy-holidays-from-app-engine-team-140.html

Comment: URLFetch allowed response size has been increased, up to 32 MB. Request size is still limited to 1 MB. and then i try th version  1.4.0,but the it still doesn't work

Comment: You asked about getting data -that is the response. But also, the 'Range' header isn't supported by every server (or even many, from what I understand).